# What is the interpretation of the quantum field operator solving the Klein-Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics, klein-gordon-equation

Does the quantum field operator $\hat \psi^\dagger(x)$ solving the KGE mean that we should think that every quantum field configuration evolves under a KGE field equation. Or do we just understand it that a specific quantum field configuration *which is created by $\hat \psi^\dagger(x)$* (i.e. a field configuration representing a single on-mass-shell matter particle at $x$) evolves like this (as it must to obey special relativity)?

Comment: The field operator satisfies the KG equation as an operator identity. It  carries information about *all possible* states. The time evolution  of physical quantities  is  accessed by taking matrix elements  of $\psi(x,t)$,  or other opertors constructed from it,  between the desired states.

Comment: Could I imagine it as almost like Greens functions. The fact that the field operator (creating a quantum of field at $x$) dynamically evolves by the KGE, and the fact that any field state can be created with enough field operators, means that any field must evolve by KGE?

Comment: What is a "quantum field configuration"? Why do you think $\psi^\dagger$ "creates" such field configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really think of "a" field configuration that is evolving in quantum field theory. You are letting some classical ideas slip into your picture.

In quantum field theory, we have some *state* of the field, $|\Psi\rangle$. Let's work in the Heisenberg picture. Then the state does not depend on time. If we expand this state in the field eigenstate basis, you can think of $|\Psi\rangle$ as assigning a probability amplitude for the field to be in any given configuration in some fixed time slice. If you like, you can think of this as a probability amplitude distribution over possible initial conditions for the field.

Of course, we can expand the state in any basis of eigenstates we like; a more common choice in particle physics is in terms of asymptotically free states with a definite number of particles (ie: a state where two electrons come in from far away).

The field operator $\phi(x, t)$ depends on space and time. Observables in quantum field theory are expressed in terms of *correlation functions* like
\begin{equation}
\langle \Psi | \phi(x_1, t_1) \phi(x_2, t_2) \cdots \phi(x_N, t_N) | \Psi \rangle
\end{equation}
Actually there are several different kinds of correlation functions. What I've written above is in the so-called *in-in* or *Schwinger-Keyldish* formalism. In describing scattering experiments in particle physics, it is actually more common to look at correlation functions of the form
\begin{equation}
\langle 0, out| T\phi(x_1, t_1) \phi(x_2, t_2) \cdots \phi(x_N, t_N) | 0, in\rangle
\end{equation}
where $|0, out\rangle$ is the vacuum (lowest-energy, zero-particle) state in the 'out' state (asymptotically far into the future), $|0, in\rangle$ is the vacuum state in the 'in' state (asymptotically far into the past), and $T$ is the *time-ordering* symbol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering#Time_ordering). Also note that by distinguishing $|0, out\rangle$ and $|0, in\rangle$, I've implicitly moved from the Heisenberg picture to the interaction picture, where for a scalar field, the field obeys the Klein-Gordon equation and the states evolve according to the interaction Hamiltonian.

The fact that $\phi(x, t)$ obeys the Klein-Gordon equation in the Heisenberg picture for a free field (or in the interaction picture for an interacting field), allows us to relate $\phi(x, t)$ to $\phi(x, t_0)$ for some reference time $t_0$ where the states are defined. Combining this evolution information, with information on how $\phi(x, t_0)$ acts on the states at $t_0$, allows us to see how correlation functions depend on time.

The main concept I want to convey in this answer is that we don't calculate *field configurations* in quantum field theory. We compute *correlation functions*. Or, more generally, we look for ways to characterize the probability amplitude distribution over possible states; in the field basis, this would mean looking for a probability amplitude distribution over possible field configurations.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between the fixed 'a state' of the quantum field, and the not fixed 'configurations' of the field?

Comment: I thought a quantum field was in a fixed configuration at a given moment in time (which can be decomposed as a superposition of states in some other basis), just like how a quantum mechanical wavefunction is fixed for a given moment in time

Comment: @AlexGower The state of a quantum field need not be a field eigenstate. In general, the state of the field is a complex superposition over field eigenstates. Intuitively, this means the state defines a probability amplitude distribution for possible configurations of the field. A typical state might assign a probability amplitude $a_1$ for the field to be in the configuration $\phi(x)=\sin(x)$, a probability amplitude $a_2$ for the field to be in the configuration $\phi(x)=e^{-x^2}$, etc.

Comment: In the Schrodinger picture of quantum field theory, the state is described by a *wave function**al***, $\Psi[\phi(x)]$, which assigns a probability amplitude to each field configuration $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Why can't the state $a_1sin(x) + a_2e^{-x^2}$ be considered as a configuration itself? Also, are you saying that quantum fields have some 'extra level of superposition' to quantum mechanical wavefunctions?

Comment: Careful. The **function** $\phi(x) = a_1 \sin(x) + a_2 e^{-x^2}$ is a field configuration. The **state** $|\Psi\rangle = a_1 |\sin(x)\rangle + a_2 |e^{-x^2}\rangle$ is not a field configuration, but a member of the Hilbert space. There is no extra level of superposition in QFT compared to QM. But, the configuration space over which the wavefunction is defined is **much** larger. Instead of the wavefunction being a function of the position of one particle or two particles, it is a function**al** of the field value at every point in space.

Comment: A common error when learning QFT is to associate the *field* with the *wave function*. This is wrong -- they are two very different things. The field configuration is analogous to the position of a classical particle (or even better, to the positions of many classical particles). The state is analogous to the wave function (well, it *is* the wavefunction).

Comment: Okay so a classical field configuration has a well-defined value at each point in space, same with a quantum *field configuration* (although I'm guessing it can only have certain quantised field configurations (corresponding to integer particles at least in free field theory?)). However a quantum field *state* can be a superposition of these quantum field configurations so you can only say things like 'you have a 50/50 change of measuring a field value of 5 or 7 at that location'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135062/discussion-between-andrew-and-alex-gower).